# Display image in grid view saved on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have a grid view in which I want to show images. I am storing images on the server and path is stored in the databse. The path is "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\BISv01\Images\Upload\Chirag.jpg"
When I fetch records from database, all columns are fetched but image is not visible in gridview. Below is the code for my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCurrency" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" onrowcommand="grdCurrency_RowCommand">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrencyID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrencyName" HeaderText="Currency" />
                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Logo" />--%>

                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="CurrencyLogo" HeaderText="Currency Logo">
                </asp:ImageField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CurrencyID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

//Below is the code to fill the gridview.

```
DataTable dtCurrency = null;
dtCurrency=oCurrency.GetAllCurrency();
if (dtCurrency != null && dtCurrency.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     grdCurrency.DataSource = dtCurrency;
     grdCurrency.DataBind();
     grdCurrency.Columns[0].Visible = false;
     lblGrdCount.Text = "Total ["+grdCurrency.Rows.Count+"] records found";
 }
```

Please help me to point out my mistake.

Comment: What do you mean with "image is not visible in gridview"? Do you see the red cross that indicates that the image was not found? If so, check if the path to the image is correct.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter. In my grid, symbol of image field are visible but no image on that fields. I am fetching the same path that I stored in databse via file upload so how that path can be wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't store the complete image path. You have to store the image path like..`'~/Images/Upload/Chirag.jpg'` in the DB.

Then this will allow you to show the image. e.g.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%#Eval("CurrencyLogo") %>' ID="Image1" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Akhatr. How to store the path that you have suggested.I am storing path like   string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Images\\Upload\\FilePath";

Comment: You can use this to store images on physical location. but when you try to save the image then use the path like.. "~\\Images\\Upload\\FilePath"

Comment: I mean generate different path to store on physical location & to store in DB.